# Redirecting to relative URL stripping some of the path

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex

I have a page located at `https://example.com/a/b/c/d/e/page?query=string` and I'd like to redirect the user to `https://example.com/a/b/c/d/e/otherpage`. I was expecting this to work:

```
window.location.href = "otherpage"
```

but that redirects to `https://example.com/a/b/otherpage`. I thought a relative URL like that would use a URL with the contents after the last slash replaced with the new URL?

Comment: It should work as expected. The problem must be that the web app is redirecting you from /a/b/c/d/e/otherpage to /a/b/otherpage

Comment: I cannot reproduce, I tried it on `example.com` and it works as expected.

Comment: Does it return the complete URL if you do a `console.log(window.location.href)` ?

Comment: i wouldn't recommend using relative URLs in your browser code

Comment: @obscure: Yes, it logs the full URL. I'm working in the Oracle Application Express framework, but I don't think anything overrides window.location.href, or if that's even possible.

Comment: @AndrewParks: The network tab in the developer tools says it's placing a GET request directly to the /a/b/otherpage URL. It's not being redirected by the server or anything.

Comment: Take a look at the web server logs and see if there is an HTTP 3XX redirect. What you are doing will definitely work as expected if the web server is not doing something unexpected. You can try on any web site. E.g. go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1 and then enter into the javascript console `window.location.href = '2'`

Comment: No redirect. This is happening in the browser before it gets to the server.

Answer (score 0):

When working in the Oracle APEX, the safest approach is to use the apex javascript apis. For navigation, there is a namespace [apex.navigation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aexjs/apex.navigation.html#.redirect). The docs has some examples for redirects.

Comment: Yes, I was using `apex.navigation.redirect` when I discovered this problem. Under the covers, all it does is use `location.href = newurl`.